# Direction of Current On Resistors

Tags: current, resistors

I am studying Kirchhoff's Law on my book and I noticed some examples.

[image]

[image]

As seen on both pictures, there are + and - signs on resistors and they decide current's direction. I don't understand how can we decide their signs? Current flows through + to - but in first picture ic flows in opposide direction. In second picture they look like assigned randomly. We just randomly assign these signs? I am really confused.

Comment: You just pick a direction for the arrow (I just use my best guess), then do the calculations. If it turns out the current has a positive value the current indeed flows in that direction. If the current has a negative value, it flows in the other direction (against the arrow). So: it does not matter if you get the direction correct or not ! Uhm, it is always correct :-) the +/- sign on the value determines the actual current flow.

Comment: Just set the sign of that current -ve (or at least opposite to the other two) and it'll all work out. It's better to assign the +/- terminals in a consistent manner, but (as fig 1 should show you) not essential.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any polarity for your analysis. Basically, you are choosing a reference direction for the current. The result is relative to that polarity -- so if you get a positive answer, then current is actually flowing in that direction (w.r.t. your initial choice of reference). If you get a negative answer, then 'negative' current is flowing in that direction, or 'positive' current is flowing in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can arbitrarily choose direction, at the end of the analysis the result will tell you if your assumption of the current direction was valid(result is positive) or the current was flowing in the opposite direction (result is negative). However, there is a convention called [Passive Sign Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) which is nothing more than a general guideline on how to assign current directions, more in passive sign convention [here](http://burkett.eng.ua.edu/ECE121131/Lectures/Passivesign-Kirchoff.pdf)